# terraform: performing a map operation on a list?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform list

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

Is there a way for me to apply a function (e.g. `*2`) on the list, to get

```
b = [2,4,6,8]
```

I was looking for an interpolation syntax, perhaps `map(a, _*2)`, or even something like

```
variable "b" {
   count = "${length(a)}"
   value = "${element(a, count.index)} * 2
}
```

As far as I can see no such thing exists. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17468). A [new version of Terraform](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-1-2-preview) was recently announced which should give the ability to do this, among many other HCL improvements.

I think currently your best bet would be to create [local values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) for each element of the list (remember that you can't use interpolation syntax in the default value of variables; locals exist to get around this limitation). However, I'm not sure if locals have a `count` attribute.

Answer (score 16):

As per @Rowan Jacob's answer, this is now possible in v0.12 using the new `for` expression.

See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions

```
variable "a" {
  type = "list"
  default = [1,2,3,4]
}

locals {
  b = [for x in var.a : x * 2]
}

output "local_b" {
  value = "${local.b}"
}
```

gives

> Outputs:
>
> local_b = [2, 4, 6, 8,]